# Bootstrap Hiding glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation bar that has two glyphicons from bootstrap the envelope and phone I want my phone icon to disappear when screen reaches <768px so I used the bootstrap class `.hidden-xs` but it doesn't work, any help? My code is

```
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"; class="hidden-xs"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how you assign multiple classes to an element. There should only ever be one `class=""` attribute...

```
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone hidden-xs"></span></a>
```

Separate the individual classes with a space.